# How to Duplicate a Project Efficiently

Tags: java, android

I have a finished project and I have to put two identical projects in the Play Store, with some changes that I will make later.

The big problem I am facing is the fact that I can not duplicate the project without the SHA1 of them being the same, I even tried to modify the package name and SHA1 continued the same.

I need projects to have different IDs because they must belong to the same project in Firebase, just like I need to post both in the Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the package name certainly changes the SHA1.

I believe my case was very specific because the project with the modified package was associated with two SHA1s, one of which was the project before renaming and this conflicted with the project that was in Firebase.

**My solution was to remove all firebase project applications and re-embed them with their new SHA1.**